# Rounded corners menu with hover backgroundcolor support all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used the li menu. I have used the border-radius for rounded corners. But is not work on ie. I need background color changes on hover menu.

Comment: Which version of IE? And where is your styles used for rounded corner?

Comment: Pls refer the following location:http://jsfiddle.net/y7cuW/. It works perfect mozilla. But Rounded corners doesn't display in ie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cross browser support, you can try
http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: Thanks. We will implement and let you know

Answer (score 0):

On IE you will have to use images for supporting rounded corners look at the sliding door technique for rounded corners in google search.

Comment: We should not use images. We need Pure css.

Comment: I guess on ie you wouldnt find a rounded corner css.

Comment: Already we have tried the "http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/" location. But hover background color doesn't works properly.

Comment: i would suggest you to then avoid rounded corner for ie8 and below. IE9 will support rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and above supports `border-radius`. I would recommend that you ignore rounded corners in IE8 and lower as it may cause a lot of tweaks just to make your layout look like the same in every browser. Just think : [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)

If however, you require it, then completely avoid using `border-radius` and just use *Sliding Doors* technique that has an image which already have rounded corners.

Here's a good tutorial about [Sliding Doors](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/).